# Getting synced array from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

Im trying to get the last 100 entries of my firebase database and have that array be dynamically updating.
The error I am getting in my console is this:

> 204 Uncaught TypeError: ref.on is not a function

I have no idea what this means.

**Code**

```
function getSynchronizedArray(firebaseRef) {
  var list = [];
  syncChanges(list, firebaseRef);
  return list;
}

function syncChanges(list, ref) {
  ref.on('child_added', function _add(snap, prevChild) {
    var data = snap.val();
    data.$id = snap.key(); 
    var pos = positionAfter(list, prevChild);
    list.splice(pos, 0, data);
  });
}


function positionFor(list, key) {
  for(var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
    if( list[i].$id === key ) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

function positionAfter(list, prevChild) {
  if( prevChild === null ) {
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    var i = positionFor(list, prevChild);
    if( i === -1 ) {
      return list.length;
    }
    else {
      return i+1;
    }
  }
}



$(function () {
        var data = [], totalPoints = 100;
        data = getSynchronizedArray('https://MYLINK.firebaseio.com/SOMETHING');
```

Thank you all very much for helping.

Comment: Seems like the last portion of your code here is cur off?

Comment: theres some stuff cut off, but that doesn't really matter, the part that doesn't work is actually getting the array filled.

Comment: You're calling `getSynchronizedArray('https://MYLINK.firebaseio.com/SOMETHING');` with a single argument, but it expects two parameters: `syncChanges(list, ref)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code ref is only a string and not a firebase reference so you have to add something like this in your code:

```
function syncChanges(list, ref) {
  var Fref = new Firebase(ref);
  Fref.on('child_added', function _add(snap, prevChild) {
```

Take a look at the firebase [documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html) for more information about this.

Comment: OK, it works now, but doesn't do exactly what i want